# Including external linked Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, brightcove

I want to include an externally hosted function/video player on a wordpress page with little to nothing else on it. The function is developed and hosted by an external provider so I have no control over it. They have provided me with the following code and instructed me to copy and paste into the page, but this doesn't work.

Unfortunately I don't have any working knowledge  of JS. Is someone able to help as to what I need to do. Do I need to edit some functions.php or should it be able to work as a one off post?

```
<!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->

<div style="display:none">

</div>

<!--
By use of this code snippet, I agree to the Brightcove Publisher T and C 
found at https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions/. 
-->


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

<object id="myExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="825" />
  <param name="height" value="650" />
  <param name="playerID" value="3058468026001" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAAACjHz08E~,HgXzSoYtBYxTAjnyep2-EpPyWh7pU7Jr" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />

</object>

<!-- 
This script tag will cause the Brightcove Players defined above it to be created as soon
as the line is read by the browser. If you wish to have the player instantiated only after
the rest of the HTML is processed and the page load is complete, remove the line.
-->
<script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>

<!-- End of Brightcove Player -->
```

It can be viewed on a page here:

http://www.treforestvets.com/pet-health-videos

Comment: No need to change anything in `functions.php`, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your code in the page source of the page provided in the link. It is commented out due to the default formatting behaviour of wordpress.

To make it work, open the editor, Remove any previous edits for that particular page and try pasting this code in `Text` mode of the Editor, not in the `Visual` mode.

After that save it and it will start working.

Comment: Thanks - I was doing all that already (I work with visual turned of) but it appears when you click 'preview' it doesn't load properly and needs a page refresh before the embedded video player works. (there is a video on youtube confirming this)